# Bootcamp Failing with Error: “The startup disk cannot be partitioned or restored to a single partition.”

Tags: mac, bootcamp, partition, error

I can't get past the error screen after the introduction.
Originally, the disk was divided in 3 partitions, the primary one with the data,the second one with the OS X reserved and the third one with bootcamp.
So I removed the bootcamp partition, and the error remains, so it's my understanding that the disk has to be in one partition.
If I delete the OS partition, will I lose any data?

My screen is something like the attatched.[image]

Comment: Boot Camp won't install to an external drive, nor will Windows boot from one -  you need some trickery. https://twocanoes.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205025389-Considerations-for-Booting-Windows-from-an-External-Drive://

Comment: @Tetsujin I have an internal hard drive with 2 partitions, one is Macintosh HD the other is OS reserved. The above screen is just a sample, not my actual partitions .

Comment: 'sample' images are only of any use when they demonstrate the actual issue :/

Comment: If I click the minus button and remove the OS partition, will the data in that partition deleted? Or joined in the bigger one? That's my basic question.

Comment: If you remove any partition everything on it will be deleted, yes.